# How to align one h1 and one h3 tag left and right on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text-align

I am trying to create bootstrap panels. I want to align the link that expands the panel to be aligned either to the left or to the center of the panel title and i want a message telling the user click to expand aligned to the right. how do i do this. i've tried displaying everything inline and using clear:none, but that does not seem to be working for me.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
      body {
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 25px;
      }
      .bg_gray {
        background-color: rgb(237, 14, 40);
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .bg_gray a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
      .navbar {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
      }
      .panel-title a{
        color: rgb(237, 14, 40);
        display: inline;
        clear: none;
      }
      .panel-body {
        background-color: rgb(237, 14, 40);
        color: white;
      }
      .panel {
        background-color: white;
        color: rgb(237, 14, 40);
      }
      .lg_expand {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        display: inline;
        clear: none;
        text-align: left;
      }
      .sm_expand {
        font-size: .8em;
        display: inline;
        clear: none;
        text-align: right;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Phillies First Round Draft Success</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "container bg_gray">
      <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class = "container">
          <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "home.html">PhillyPhigures.com</a>
          <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href = "phillies_articles.html">Phillies</a></li>
            <li><a href = "eagles_articles.html">Eagles</a></li>
            <li><a href = "flyers_articles.html">Flyers</a></li>
            <li><a href = "sixers_articles.html">Sixers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <center><h1>Do the Phillies Draft Successfully in the First Round?</h1></center>
      <center><h4>~Tyler Grim | May 8, 2017</h4></center>
      <hr/>
      <p>With the Major League Baseball Amateur Draft set for June 12, 2017,
        and the Philadelphia Phillies holding the 8th pick in that draft,
        many Phillies fans are left wondering whether the next big thing will
        be brought to Philadelphia.</p>
      <p>Last season, the Phillies drafted Mackenzie "Mickey" Moniak with the
        first overall pick in the 2016 MLB Draft. Moniak joined Pat Burrell as
        the only players selected first overall by the Phillies in the amateur
        draft. Burrell had a long successful career with the Phillies after
        being drafted #1 overall in 1995 Amateur Draft. Phillies fans would be more
        than pleased to see Moniak produce the way Burrell did in his nine seasons
        with Philadelphia.
      </p>
      <hr/><center>Pat Burrell Career Phillies Stats</center><hr/>
      <table class = "table">
        <tr>
          <th>Years</th><th>WAR</th><th>AB</th><th>R</th><th>H</th><th>2B</th><th>3B</th><th>HR</th><th>RBI</th><th>BA</th><th>OBP</th><th>SLG</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td><td>18.8</td><td>4535</td><td>655</td><td>1166</td><td>253</td><td>14</td><td>251</td><td>827</td><td>.257</td><td>.367</td><td>.485</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <hr/><center>Stats Courtesy of <a href = "http://www.baseball-reference.com">Baseball-Reference</a></center><hr/>
      <p>However, have the Phillies always enjoyed success in drafting in the first round of the amateur draft Let's take a look at the
        Phillies recent first round draft picks to see how they've performed.</p>
      <div class = "panel-group">
        <div class = "panel panel-default">
          <div class = "panel-heading">
            <h4 class = "panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                <h1 class = "lg_expand"><strong>2016</strong>: Mickey Moniak | OF | Costa Canyon HS, CA</h1>
              </a>
                <h3 class = "sm_expand">(click to expand)</h3>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class = "panel-body">
              <p>Moniak is currently the Phillies second rated prospect, behind only JP Crawford, and is the #16 prospect in all of baseball.
                Moniak projects to be a future outfielder in the Phillies system and has turned heads so far in the Gulf Coast League and
                with Lakewood. Moniak currently sports a BA/OBP/SLG of .283/.339/.394, in 28 games with Lakewood so far in 2017.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `float: left` to **h1** and `float: right` to **h3**, while adding a blank div just before **h4** closing tag that does `clear: both` should do it. Additionally, you can style that div to set custom margin if you like.

Something like this?:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmyyJP

Comment: should the blank div be opened and close before the h4?

Comment: yes, in the example above, it's `<div class="clearer"></div>`